# Raspberry Pi3にUbuntu Mate16.04を入れてフォルダを英語表記にしたらBluemanでエラーがでる。

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi3にUbuntu Mate16.04を入れて、以下でフォルダを英語表記にしました。

```
LANG=C xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
```

そうしたら、自動起動されていたbluemanで以下のようなエラーがでるようになりました。
解決方法を教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` や `xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD` で状況を調査してみて下さい。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
試して見ましたが、以下のような結果となってます。
次はどうしたらよいかを教えていただけないでしょうか？

:~$ cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs  
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"  
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"  
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"  
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"  
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"  
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"  
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"  
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"  
:~$ xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD  
/home/rpi3/Downloads

Comment: xdgの設定は正しくできていますね。bluemanの設定はxdgに追随しないんですね。(なお、追加の情報などはコメントでなく投稿を編集する事で追加する事になっています‌​。そうすれば他の方の目にも触れるので、次回はそうしてみて下さい。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ローカルサービスで"Incoming Folder"が設定されておらずDownloadsと設定しなおすことで
解決しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: こういった設定は設定ファイルではなくdconfという設定システムに集められている事があります。アプリケーション側に設定インターフェイスが見あたらない場合は`dconf-editor`などで閲覧、変更出来ます。`gsettings`や`dconf`といったコマンドも用意されていますから、`gsettings set org.blueman.transfer shared-path ~/Downloads` という風にコマンドラインで設定する事も出来ます。(なお、この回答で解決にいたった場合は回答を「承認」しておいて下さい。自分の回答を承認できるまでには待ち時間があるようですが。）